# How can I mock a nested 'this' function in Jest for Vue?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, mocking

I'm testing a Vue component which is outside a normal Vue project structure (so for the purposes of this question it can be imagined as a standalone `.vue` file).

In the `mounted()` lifecycle hook I am calling a function which follows the following format:

`this.$parent.$someValue.$getSomeData();`

This would ordinarily be passed down the context when the file is in its proper place, but as it is standalone, how do I mock this with Jest?

I've tried adding it into mocks when mounting, `spyOn` and directly assigning it, such as by using `wrapper.vm.$parent.$someValue.$getSomeData = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('');`

Comment: It's a bad practice to use $parent for several reasons, one of them is that it's more difficult to test. In this case you'll have to mock component hierarchy, so fake parent has this property

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! So would creating a mock parent component with the $helpers variable as a data item which itself contains the $getUser function work?

Comment: For example:

`const Parent = { data: () => ({$helpers: {$getUser: () => { return '' }}}), template: '<div />'}`

Comment: Yes, something like that. Needs to have a child in the template.

Comment: So I've made the template section look like this: `template: '<div><u-ComponentName></u-ComponentName></div>'`, and the actual child component tries to use the $getUser() function inside its `mounted()` lifecycle hook, but it still says `cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$getUser')`. If I make it try to access just $helpers (not as a function), it works fine, it's when I try to have it have three 'levels' or make the last one a function.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on there at that point, in case it's Vue 3, $ properties are handled in a special way there iirc, could be the case. Any way, I'd strongly suggest to handle this through events and get rid of $parent, it exists for historical reasons (borrowed from AngularJS where it was an antipattern already)